# Why am I getting 404 error after Ubuntu upgrade?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Update:

OK, I'm planning on working with someone to get the site updated ;) , but in the meantime (as I said) I really need to get the site up-and-running. The issue I am having is that the rvm make is failing on that (very old) Ruby version that I need:

`Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /home/<user>/.rvm/log/1567793172_ruby-1.8.7-p357/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.`

I looked in the log file and it's very long and (to my eyes) incomprehensible, but I've done some research and apparently the most likely issue is that the ssl 1.0 libs (?) are missing. Some folks have used:

`apt install libssl1.0-dev openssl1.0`

but I'm on a shared hosted server and don't have root access so that doesn't work for me.

Again, I know this is incredibly outdated and I should expect it to work, but if anyone has any ideas I'd be grateful.

======================

Our site was broken (again) when my hosting service upgraded to to Ubuntu Linux version 18.04.1 LTS.

My apologies for my (severely) limited knowledge - the site was put together years ago by a vendor and now as I.T. guy it's fallen on me (I'm well-versed in infrastructure, Windows Server, etc., but not this).

The site is running Ruby on Rails. After the last upgrade (to Ubuntu 16.x AIR) I had issues, and I dove in and with some help from folks here I figured out how to use and install gems, so I managed to install a newer version of Ruby and all the other the requisite gems and got everything working again.

Now I'm trying to get Ruby 2.5.x running. I've installed it and upgraded all the gems, ruby -v shows 2.5.6, Rails shows 6.0.0, Phusion Passenger 6.0.2. I haven't touched any of the site code, other than specifying the newer version numbers in environment.rb and preinitializer.rb.

I must be missing something completely basic because although the main page loads just fine, any subpage throws:

`Not Found
The requested URL /home/join was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

so I'm thinking however the paths are being constructed is broken somehow. I did see something online about "." and ".." path constructions having been changed in latest Ubuntu, so I'm wondering if that's related. The folder structure is standard:

`home/username/me.com/public
home/username/me.com/config`

etc.

and again, I haven't moved anything.

The last time I was at least getting some meaningful errors from Passenger, but I'm not even getting that now. It doesn't seem to be writing anything to the log files, either.

Apologies again for the basic question. Thank you for anything at all that can point me int the right direction.

Comment: "I'm trying to get Ruby 2.5.x running." -- What version of Ruby was the site running before, when it was working?  Updating Ruby versions can require code changes to the app.  If possible, use the same major/minor version of Ruby (but latest patch level) as the site was using.  If Ubuntu doesn't have that version, then uninstall system Ruby and use rvm or rvenv to pin down the exact version of Ruby your site needs.  Don't give the distro control over what Ruby version an app is using.

Comment: It was a very old version, 1.9.x. I've gotten familiar with RVM enough that I thought of going back to that, but I'd really like to avoid this every time they upgrade Ubuntu.

I guess you're saying I should learn Ruby, but I don't really have the time or inclination tbh.

Comment: 1.9 is no longer supported, as far as I know, so it would be good for your business to upgrade.  From 1.9 to 2.5 is a bit of a jump--there will almost certainly be code changes, either to your app directly, or to libraries that the app uses (it is not unusual for Rails, or some other library, to need to be upgraded before it can be run on a later version of Ruby)...

Comment: ...Your choices are either to use rvm to keep the same version of Ruby, and take the security hit (because 1.9 is no longer supported), or learn some Ruby in order to get the app on the latest Ruby (and possibly a later version of Rails as well, which is seldom a trivial project).  Neither choice looks really super, I'm afraid.  One has a lot of risk, the other has a (potentially) lot of work.

Comment: Right. Well, my concern right now is just to get the site up-and-running again. I might just try and revert it for now until I figure out what to do in the long run.

And actually, it was even worse (I just went and looked), version 1.8.7-p357

I'm not even sure I still wouldn't have issues - it used the mysql gem, which wouldn't even install on this Ubuntu. It looks like I'd have to switch to mysql2. I started toying with that, but since I couldn't even get the site up at all...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The switch from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 was huge, involving big code changes.  It's the biggest single change that Ruby ever did, so... wow.  I'm sorry you're having to go through that, and no Ruby dev.